# How to use sklearn FeatureHasher?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.DataFrame({'type': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b'], 'model': ['bab', 'ba', 'ba', 'ce', 'bw']})
```

How do I use the `sklearn` `FeatureHasher`
on it?

I tried:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import FeatureHasher 
FH = FeatureHasher()
train = FH.transform(test.type)
```

but it doesn't like it? it seems it wants a string or a list so I try

```
FH.transform(test.to_dict(orient='list'))
```

but that doesn't work either?
I get:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

thanks

Comment: Does `FH.transform(test['type'].tolist())` work?

Comment: Instead of `FH.transform(test.to_dict(orient='list'))` use `FH.transform(test.to_dict(orient='records'))`. `orient='records'` will convert the dataframe into a list of dictionaries which can then be processed by `FeatureHasher`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to specify the input type when initializing your instance of [FeatureHasher](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.FeatureHasher.html):

```
In [1]:
from sklearn.feature_extraction import FeatureHasher
h = FeatureHasher(n_features=5, input_type='string')
f = h.transform(test.type)
f.toarray()

Out[1]:
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Note that this will assume the value of these feature is 1 according to the documentation linked above (bold emphasis is mine):

> **input_type : string, optional, default “dict”**
>
> - Either “dict” (the default) to accept dictionaries over (feature_name, value);
> - “pair” to accept pairs of (feature_name,
>     value);
> - or “string” to accept single strings. feature_name should be a
>     string, while value should be a number. **In the case of “string”, a
>     value of 1 is implied**.
>
> The feature_name is hashed to find the
>   appropriate column for the feature. The value’s sign might be flipped
>   in the output (but see non_negative, below).

Comment: ok that is returning something but not what I thought it was going to return

Comment: Well that's a different problem than this question, which I think I answered. What were you expecting?

Comment: Say I have a table: `Article|Category` each `Article` has many `category` I want one hash result per article to `left_join` as a feature back into my dataset. when I get the table in I got a `(2x n_features)` frame back. Or am I not understanding the use of feature hashing in general?

Comment: should  I dummy first before putting it into the feature hasher?

Comment: I think it's an interesting question, worth asking as an actual question on SO or on datascience.stackexchange.com.

Comment: And no, you shouldn't use dummy variables (=one-hot encoding) because one-hot encoding and feature hashing ultimately serve the same purpose of converting categorical data into numeric data (as needed per ML algorithms).

Comment: I agree w/ @JulienMarrec that the second question is interesting. Was it asked?